# .epub on iPhone

Tags: iphone, epub, ebook-reader

Seeking your help to get off .epub(s) sea in iPhone world...

I am trying to make an iPhone application which can read .epub(s). So, I'm in search of a good method, API, Webservices, etc. which help me to render .epub(s) on iPhone's screen. Please let me know once you got any information about .epub(s) on iPhone.

=> My application would be like, Stanza/Calibri, which can read .epub(s).

Thanking You...
Paresh Thakor

Comment: This is a duplicate of the following questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287130/loading-an-epub-simple-epub-reader-question , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388467/reading-epub-format , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440513/how-to-show-the-xmdf-and-the-epub-extension-file-on-the-iphone

Comment: Sory DUDE...! But you're making comments as duplicate question, hah? but i want answer..! and i've searched those all questions and web pages habing 'epub' but I've found nothing which can satisfy me...

answers on that questions are not working perfect for my satisfaction..!

Please help me out if you got any solution, I wanna access full epub features and make iPhone application, I'm strongly in search for framework / api, 

Thank You

Comment: hi,Paresh Thakor,do you have found a solution,i guess,if you have found ,maybe you could give me some help .help me ,or maybe we could discuss it together.

Comment: Sorry buddy, but i've left the searching of it due to time limitations. But it would be of use if we can discuss and derive a solution.

Thanks for your back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EPUB is just XHTML stored in a zipfile with an XML manifest. Get a zip library and you can use a WebView to display the actual content.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply...
I'm going to definitely try the method...

But, hmmm..., I don't know if objective c has in-built support for manipulation / extraction of zip files. And from those extracted files, which file we should use to display in WebView? Are not .epub s are XML files? Will they be display in good manners this way?

If you know any zip library which provides easy api with objective c, then, please let me know..!

Thanking You,
Paresh Thakor

Comment: If you need zip support, here's a nice library I have used: http://code.google.com/p/ziparchive/