# Reading Epub File in iphone SDK

Tags: iphone

How can I read .epub files like iBook application of apple?
Is there any SDK or just java script.
If anyone has any idea please let me know.

Thank You.

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713730/epub-on-iphone

Answer (score 0):

Just unzip the ePub file and point a `UIWebView` at the resulting HTML.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i have done that but i want same effect as iphone iBook has page sliding type.so how can i get that from?

Comment: @iGuru: you need to write code to do that. What have you tried?